# How to use parallel computing for missRanger in imputation of missing values?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, missing-data, imputation

I am imputing missing values by `missRanger` and it takes too long as I have 1000 variables. I tried to use parallel computing, but it does not make the process faster. Here is the code

```
library(doParallel)
cores=detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(cores[1]-1) 
registerDoParallel(cl)
library(missRanger)
train[1:lengthvar] <- missRanger(train[1:lengthvar], pmm.k = 3, num.trees = 100)
stopCluster(cl)
```

I am not sure what to add to this code to make it work.

Comment: Can you provide a small dataset with say 3 or 4 columns? Run the code on that dataset and post the exact error code.

Comment: This code does not have any error. The point is that adding the parallel computing does not expedite the process of imputing at all. I was wondering what I could add to make the parallel work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`missRanger` is based on a parallelized random forest implementation in R -`ranger`. Thus, the code is already running on all cores and stuff like `doParallel` just renders the code clumsy.

Try to speed up the calculations by passing relevant arguments to `ranger` via the `...` argument of `missRanger`, e.g.

- `num.trees = 20` or
- `max.depth = 8`

instead.

Disclaimer: I am the author of `missRanger`.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is great.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic example of the concept of multiple cores. This will highlight the basic concept instead of looking at the timing issue. By my test runs (for larger number of columns), the non parallel version is faster.

```
library(doParallel)
library(missRanger)
library(data.table) #Needed for rbindlist at the end
cores=detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(cores[1]) 
registerDoParallel(cl)
clusterEvalQ(cl, {library(missRanger)}) #Passing the package missRanger to all the cores
#Create some random columns
A=as.numeric(c(1,2,"",4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,"",15,16,17,18,19,20))
B=as.numeric(c(120.5,128.1,126.5,122.5,127.1,129.7,124.2,123.7,"",122.3,120.9,122.4,125.7,"",128.2,129.1,121.2,128.4,127.6,125.1))
m = as.data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 10, nrow = 20))
m[,1:5]=A
m[,6:10]=B
list_num=as.data.frame(seq(1,10,by=1)) #A sequence of column numbers for the different cores to run the function for

#Note that the optimal process would have been to take columns 1:3
#and run it on one core, 4:6 to run it on the 2nd core and so on.

#Function to run on the parallel cores

zzz=function(list_num){
  m_new=m[,list_num] #Note the function takes the column number as an argument
  m_new=missRanger(m_new[1:length(m_new)], pmm.k = 3, num.trees = 100)
}

clusterExport(cl=cl, list("m"),envir=environment()) #Export your list
zz=parLapply(cl=cl,fun=zzz,X=list_num) #Pass the function and the list of numbers here
zzzz=data.frame(rbindlist(zz)) #rbind the 
stopCluster(cl)
```

Answer (score 0):

`mice 3.15.0` and later has a new `futuremice()` function that provides parallel processing. It can be used to impute missing data by `ranger::ranger()` through the "rf" method.